# Python beginner question: How do I obtain a range from this set of data (question and attempt included)

Tags: python

I am taking a beginners course and I'm trying to find where i am going wrong on this question.
I have searched and found a similar thread but I still can't get the answer right!

Question 3
You've been given data from WHO of deaths from TB in various countries including:

```
Population by country
Country         Deaths from TB
South Africa    25 000
Mozambique      18 000
Angola          6 900
Equatorial Guinea   67
Guinea-Bissau   1 200
```

You have been given a partially completed Python function called rangeOfDeaths to calculate the range of the deaths which should return the range of deaths in 5 African countries.

These deaths in each country  have already been assigned for you to variables: `deathsInSA`, `deathsInM`, `deathsInA`, `deathsInEG` and `deathsInGB`.

Add the additional lines of code necessary for result to hold the difference between the largest and smallest number of deaths. This should be a positive number.

You should make use of the Python functions you have learned about this week in your code.

Hint 1: You will need to make use of local variables in this function.

Hint 2: Make sure your code is all indented correctly or it will not run.

```
def rangeOfDeaths():
    deathsInSA = 25000
    deathsInM = 18000
    deathsInA = 6900
    deathsInEG = 67
    deathsInGB = 1200

    return result

def rangeOfDeaths(deathsInSA, deathsInM, deathsInA, deathsInEG, deathsInGB):
    deathsInSA = 25000
    deathsInM = 18000
    deathsInA = 6900
    deathsInEG = 67
    deathsInGB = 1200
    largest = max(deathsInSA, deathsInM, deathsInA, deathsInEG, deathsInGB)
    smallest = min(deathsInSA, deathsInM, deathsInA, deathsInEG, deathsInGB)
    result = (largest - smallest)
    return result

Feedback
Expected    Got 
24933
***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 39, in <module>
    print(rangeOfDeaths())
TypeError: rangeOfDeaths() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'deathsInSA', 'deathsInM', 'deathsInA', 'deathsInEG', and 'deathsInGB'
Your code must pass all tests to earn any marks. Try again.
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have to submit a file for this question. What is the code submission system looking for?

Comment: You are getting the error `rangeOfDeaths() missing 5 required positional arguments` because you have two functions named `rangeOfDeaths`, one of which expects 5 arguments.

Comment: Hi, Sorry the first def refers what is given, the 2nd def refers to my attempt to complete the code and the third chunk is the error I get when submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Having just completed this question myself (and after a lot of digging around the internet) I made this solution:

```
def rangeOfDeath():
    deathsInSA = 25000
    deathsInM = 18000
    deathsInA = 6900
    deathsInEG = 67
    deathsInGB = 1200
    
    maxD = max(deathsInSA, deathsInM, deathsInA, deathsInEG, deathsInGB)
    minD = min(deathsInSA, deathsInM, deathsInA, deathsInEG, deathsInGB)
    result = maxD - minD
    
    return result

rangeOfDeath()
```

Do all the calculations in the def rangeOfDeath(): module and then simply call the module from outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function rangeOfDeaths() and return result from there. No need to add arguments to the function. If you add arguments then you will have to pass them too to call the function which is not required here.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this tomorrow